# How can I limit the amount of certain characters in an input field?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm looking to create a phone number input which needs 1 "+" character at the beginning of it, but the user doesn't have to use it, instead they can use "00".

The thing I'm trying to achieve is to not allow the user to input a "+" unless it's the first character?

Comment: Can you show your code? Or anything that you've started with?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `pattern` attribute on your input field. Something like this, maybe.

You can use `checkValidity` to programmatically validate the input pattern.

```js
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = () => {
  const isValid = document.getElementById("number").checkValidity();
  console.log({ isValid })
}
```

```css
input:invalid { color: red; }
input:valid { color: green; }
```

```html
<input id="number" required type="text" pattern="(?:\+|00)[1-9]\d{5,17}" placeholder="+555555">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a regular expression to the [`pattern attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) of the input to warn users that they've added an invalid number. [More tests](https://regex101.com/r/nc6Ut6/1).

And then you can use the same regex in your JS code to either submit the number or not.

`^` indicates the start of the string

`[+|00]`: either a `+` or `00`

`\d+`: all numbers until we reach the end of the string `$`.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleSubmit, false);

const regex = /^(\+|00)\d+$/;

function handleSubmit() {
  if (regex.test(input.value)) {
    console.log('Submit');
  } else {
    console.log('Wrong number');
  }
}
```

```css
input:invalid { border: red solid 3px; }
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^(\+|00)\d+$" />
<button>Submit</button>
```